# how will be the regular expression in php for url pattern which doesn't start with "/ap1/v1"

Tags: php, regex

I am trying regular expression in php for url pattern matches url which doesnt start with "/api/v1".

```
^(?!/api/v1.*$).*
```

isn't working for me.

I am trying to configure it in symfony security config to match url patter for symfony security firewall

```
main:
    pattern: '^(?!/api/v1.*$).*'
```

Comment: Can you provide sample strings? That seems to work in the cases I've tried https://regex101.com/r/tIqREE/1/

Comment: Probably, you used it wrong, try `if (preg_match('~^(?!/api/v1).*~', $url)) {return true;}`

Comment: I am trying to configure it in symfony security config to match firewall url pattern, I mentioned it as it is mentioned in question. Updated question

Comment: Patterns aren't enclosed between quote in yaml config files. Try to remove the quotes. Also, you can remove the useless `.*$` in the lookahead.

Comment: Yeah, looks like you need `pattern: ^(?!/api/v1)`

Comment: Does `pattern: ^(?!/api/v1)` work for you?

Answer (score -1):

When I ran your expression through [regexr.com](https://regexr.com) it said `ERROR: Unescaped forward slash. This may cause issues if copying/pasting this expression into code.`

Adding a backslash before each of your forward slashes removed the error. Give this a try `^(?!\/api\/v1.*$).*`